# Headless PI not booting anymore after upgrade and nordvpn install

Tags: boot, pi-zero, headless

my Pi apparently stopped working after `apt upgrade` and installing `nordvpn` app. The thing is that I see a red line at the bottom of my `var/log/syslog`.

In practice I can't ssh anymore in it.
I checked if the ssh configuration and looks good. However when I ping the static local IP assigned `198.168.1.223`, it gets unresolved. Also the PI Led stays red.

Do you have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you read var/log/syslog from some other computer? try editing the file using a simple editor, that way you'll be able to see the full text for that last log entry

Comment: Have you checked if it has another IP? 
Have you connected a screen to it and checked the logs there?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what **YOU** did, what OS or what is connected.

You have apparently tried to install some networking app on a Pi with no networking hardware.

Changing networking on a headless system is a very poor practice.

One thing that can be read from the unclear image is "IP address changed to 10.…"

**WHY are you trying to ping 198.168.1.223?**

You may have attempted to set a static IP address (which is a Pi disease) - probably the most common question asked on this site, usually by people with little understanding of networking.

Comment: Breathe and cool down :D :D :D... remoteit is quite the best practice if you want to expose PI from outside your network, in a safe way, which is what I needed. For the same reason, a static IP address (198.168.1.223), gives reliability within the local network, in which other devices are connected. Spoiler: I just re-installed the system. It was nordvpn app to mess up configuration, I will go for openvpn.